# PySpark error Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.fit

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, pipeline

I'm new to Spark and I'm learning ML with PySpark. I have tested code from PySpark doc but I'm getting this error "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.fit."

Link to PySpark doc that I used: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/ml-pipeline.html#example-estimator-transformer-and-param

Pyton verison: Python 3.8.8rc1,
PySpark version: 3.2.1,
py4j: 0.10.9.3

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

training = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.1, 0.1])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.0, -1.0])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.3, 1.0])),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.2, -0.5]))], ["label", "features"])

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01)
print("LogisticRegression parameters:\n" + lr.explainParams() + "\n")

model1 = lr.fit(training)
```

Here you have full logs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Program Files (x86)\Programowanie\Mastering-Big-Data-Analytics-with-PySpark\work\MachineLearning\5-4.ipynb Cell 3' in <module>
      1 # Learn a LogisticRegression model. This uses the parameters stored in lr.
----> 2 model1 = lr.fit(training)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyspark\ml\base.py:161, in Estimator.fit(self, dataset, params)
    159         return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    160     else:
--> 161         return self._fit(dataset)
    162 else:
    163     raise TypeError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "
    164                     "but got %s." % type(params))

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py:335, in JavaEstimator._fit(self, dataset)
    334 def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 335     java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    336     model = self._create_model(java_model)
    337     return self._copyValues(model)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py:332, in JavaEstimator._fit_java(self, dataset)
    318 """
    319 Fits a Java model to the input dataset.
    320 
   (...)
    329     fitted Java model
    330 """
    331 self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 332 return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    109 def deco(*a, **kw):
    110     try:
--> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
    112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) ("DESKTOP-NAME" executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.$anonfun$compute$1(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.withExistingConf(SQLConf.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:175)
    ... 48 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2309)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$fold$1(RDD.scala:1183)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1177)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$1(RDD.scala:1246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1222)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Summarizer$.getClassificationSummarizers(Summarizer.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.$anonfun$train$1(LogisticRegression.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:495)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.$anonfun$compute$1(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.withExistingConf(SQLConf.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:175)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: did you get resolve it ? Unfortunately I'm facing this issue now.

Comment: Hi,
Yes, I have resolved it! I solved the problem by changing the Python and PySpark version. Now I'm using:

Python: 3.7.9
PySpark: 2.4.8